# Regex expression starting from a certain character

Tags: r, regex

Example: `"example._AL(5)._._4500_GRE/Jan_2018"`
I am trying to extract text from the above string containing parentheses. I wanna extract everything starting from `AL`.

Output should look like: `"AL(5)._._4500_GRE/Jan_2018"`

Comment: A simple `"(AL.+)"` should do it

Comment: Then why are you tagging Python and Javascript?

Comment: Make an attempt bro ...

Answer (score 1):

There is some question on what we can assume is known but here are a few variations which make various assumptions.

**1) word(** This removes everything prior to the first word followed by a parenthesis.

- "^" matches the start of string
- ".*?" is the shortest match of anything provided we still match rest of regex
- "\\w+" matches a word
- "\\(" matches a left paren
- (...) forms a capture group which the replacement string can refer to as "\\1"

Code

```
x <- "example.AL(5)._._4500_GRE/Jan_2018"
sub("^.*?(\\w+\\()", "\\1", x)
## [1] "AL(5)._._4500_GRE/Jan_2018"
```

**1a)** or matching a word followed by ( followed by anything and extracting that:

```
library(gsubfn)
strapplyc(x, "\\w+\\(.*", simplify = TRUE)
## [1] "AL(5)._._4500_GRE/Jan_2018"
```

**2) AL(** or if we know that the word is `AL` then:

```
sub("^.*?(AL\\(.*)", "\\1", x)
## [1] "AL(5)._._4500_GRE/Jan_2018"
```

**3) remove up to 1st dot** or if we know that the part to be removed is the part before and including the first dot:

```
sub("^.*?\\.", "", x)
## [1] "AL(5)._._4500_GRE/Jan_2018"
```

**4) dot separated fields** If the format of the input is dot-separated fields we can parse them all out at once like this:

```
read.table(text = x, sep = ".", as.is = TRUE)
##        V1    V2 V3                 V4
## 1 example AL(5)  _ _4500_GRE/Jan_2018
```

Comment: Also just `sub("^.+(?=AL)", "", "example._AL(5)._._4500_GRE/Jan_2018", perl=TRUE)`, using lookahead to remove anything that is at the beginning of string followed by `"AL"`

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: @dishdash if the answer solved your problem please accept it